# Windows service starting, but stopping immediately without errors after OnStart()

Tags: c#, windows-services, 32bit-64bit, remote-desktop

I've recently converted a TCP-port listening application into a Windows Service, which installs and runs perfectly on my 32bit Vista laptop.
The problem was, after its installation, which works, I attempted to run the service(through Remote Dekstop) on a 64bit Win7 and it neatly handed me an error 1053, basically stating that the service timed out while starting up.

Now I've gotten it to start up without errors, but all it does is exit immediately without any errors or any eventLogging past OnStart.
I've tried replacing my Timer with Threading to see if that might have been the issue with the strange start, but no luck there... Here's the OnStart method of the service and the method that is meant to run continously.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myServer.Start();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server started.");               
        mWorker = new Thread(StartUp);
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Starting up CykelScore service.");
        mWorker.Start();//Start the service
        //timer.Start();              // Start the timer
    }
```

---

```
    private void StartUp(object arg)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Running.");
            if (mStop.WaitOne(10000)) return;
            {
                if (Monitor.dataCount > 0)
                {
                    string tmp = "";
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Antal tags: " + Monitor.dataCount.ToString());
                    lockedUp.WaitOne();
                    try
                    {
                        tmp = Monitor.PopData();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Fejl:" + ex.ToString());
                    }
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Recieved: " + tmp);
                    string buffer = tmp;
                    string antenna = (buffer.Split(',')[0]).Replace(" ", "");
                    string time = buffer.Split(',')[2];
                    string RFIDNR = (buffer.Split(',')[1]).Replace(" ", "");

                    string[] ART = new string[3];
                    ART[0] = antenna;
                    ART[1] = RFIDNR;
                    ART[2] = time;

                    if (lastreceivedtagID == RFIDNR)
                    {
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Same tag as last time. No need to check database");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!DataHandler.LoggedInCurrentTimespan(ART))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DataHandler.SaveToLocal(ART);
                                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Data saved to local database");

                                DataHandler.SendToRemote(tmp, Monitor.server, Monitor.database, Monitor.username, Monitor.password);
                                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Data sent to remote database");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Fejl" + ex.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Discarding data. Already in local database");
                    }
                    lastreceivedtagID = RFIDNR;
                    lockedUp.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: I wouldn't think that it's a 32/64 bit issue.  The best way I can think of to find out what the issue is would be to write a wrapper around your service that calls the start/stop routines without the need for the service manager.  Then you can start that program using a remote debugging session and see where the start routine is hanging up.

Comment: Assume a problem in your OnStart() method.  Add logging to diagnose it.

Comment: Look in th event viewer and see if it shows any errors. You did check to see if anything was already listening on the port you service is using on the Win7 box ?

Comment: Now I've got it able to start up, but in a second it stops without any notice. There's nothing else listening on the port - I've got eventlogging going on at the OnStart, which shows me that it runs through there and finishes the OnStart method - but the Timer that it starts apparently doesnt get to call the following methods, or something else goes wrong that I'm not aware.

Comment: Are you using any external dll's?

Comment: Not that I know of(I didn't make the application). Though it should still run, as the application, pre-windows-service, still runs on the server I'm trying to get it to run on, and I've only added System references.